# Three.js Render will show on simple page but not in mine

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a very very stragne problem. I hace created a 3D Model with three.js. The model is displaying fine and all the functions are correct in the testing page i made it. Now, when i import it in my page inside other divs etc.. my object is not displaying, when i refresh the page WITHOUT changing the code the object MIGHT display, sometimes it does sometimes it does not.. very strange. Has anybody experience a similar problem? Thanks! If you need to see the code just say so.

Comment: does your app still use the full browser page or only part of it?

Comment: This is the div        '<div id ="webGL-container" style="width:600px; height:400px; margin-left:540px; z-index:10000; background-color:white">
        ee
        </div>'
the id calls the object. In the testing page the div is on the top. On the other you have to scroll to see it.

Comment: and hello gaitat! :)

Comment: in this case you will find valuable info here http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-anti-patterns.html. granted it is for GL but same concepts apply when you are not drawing in the full browser window.

Comment: Thanks, I' ll read later and i will send feedback. Have a good day!